# invalid django form makes is_valid method always return false

Tags: python, django, forms, user-interface

My django form is invalid and so the .is_valid method never returns true. As a result, I am getting an "Expected HttpResponse but received None" type of error because my code never executes what is within the if-condition. I am wondering how to make my form valid. I am new to django so I am probably missing something obvious. Here is my code:

views.py

```
  template_name1 = 'multiplication/detail.html'
  template_name2 = 'multiplication/multiplied.html'

  class myForm(forms.Form):
    quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    quantity2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

  form = myForm()

  def get(request):
    return render(request,template_name1,{'form': form} )

  def multiply_two_integers(x,y):
    return x*y

  def post(request):
    if (form.is_valid()):
      x = request.POST.get('quantity1')
      y = request.POST.get('quantity2')
      product = multiply_two_integers(x, y)
      return render(request, template_name2, {'form': form, 'product': 
      product })
```

template_name1

```
   <h1>Multiplication Function</h1>
   <form action =  "{% url 'multiplication:post' %}" method = "post">
   {{ form.as_p  }}
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type = "submit" value ="Multiply">
   <!--<button type="submit"> Multiply </button>-->
   <h1>{{product}}</h1>
   </form>
```

template_name2

```
   <h1>{{product}}</h1>
```

urls/multiplication

```
   from django.urls import path
   from multiplication import views
   app_name = 'multiplication'
   urlpatterns = [
   # /multiplication/
   path('', views.get, name = 'get'),
   path('multiplied', views.post, name='post')
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is very strange. You seem to have a set of functional views, but are trying to randomly use some concepts from class-based views.

The reason why your form is not valid is because you never pass any data to it; an unbound form cannot be valid. You should not be instantiating the form outside of a view; you need to do it in the view, and when the request is a POST you should pass the POST data to it.

In function-based views you should not define separate functions for get and post. Combine them, as sown in the Django docs.

There is another point that you have missed about the error message; your reaction to it telling you that you have not returned a response if the form is invalid is to ask "why isn't it valid", but you should *also* do what it says and return a response in this case; the form will sometimes be actually invalid, and you should deal with this case.

Finally, to get the data from the form you should use `form.cleaned_data`, not `request.POST`.

```
def multiply_two_integers(x,y):
    return x*y

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid()):
            x = form.cleaned_data['quantity1']
            y = form.cleaned_data['quantity2']
            product = multiply_two_integers(x, y)
            return render(request, template_name2, {'product': product })
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request,template_name1,{'form': form} )
```

Comment: but then how should I change the urls.py ?